# How to select (remove) every 6th (Nth) line in a text file?

Tags: notepad++

I need to reformat a log file of similar format and have been using Notepad++ macros.

Example:

```
[00:55:48] Profile Information:

[00:55:48] Name: Joe Bloggs

[00:55:48] Age: 21

[00:55:48] Profile Information:

[00:55:48] Name: Joe Bloggs 2

[00:55:48] Age: 22
```

I need the format to be:

```
Joe Bloggs
21
Joe Bloggs 2
22
```

I can do this with the following operations in a macro but that only gets me so far.

Remove timestamps
[[^[]]*]

Remove empty lines
Edit > Line Operations > Remove Empty Lines

Replace following with nothing
Name: 
Age:

Then I would need to select every say, 2nd line and remove everything else so I am left with a list of every second line - something like:

```
21
22
```

Hoping someone more familiar with Regex and such can chime in with pointers and advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are asking for.
You title is about selecting every 7th line in a textfile but your sample is not related to that.

Anyway, I am guessing that you want to select every 7th line in a text file with notepad++.

You can do something like this:

1. Remove the empty lines: Edit > Line Operations > Remove Empty Lines
2. With Search & Replace(on regular expression mode) you can use this expression:

   - Search: `([^\n]*\n?){7}`
   - Replace: `$1`

**P.S. If you want another nth line, just replace the number between the braces.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find and replace using ctrl-f in notepad++ and entering the following regex:

```
\[[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]] Profile Information:
\[[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]]
```

The first replaces the line with the "Profile Information", the second all the time stamps.

You can find information [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Embellishments) about regular expressions. Also I suggest this [cheetsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) which helps a lot.